# ¿Como cambiar la tecla para aceptar una sugerencia de la terminal Linux?

Tags: zsh

Por ejemplo tengo la siguiente sugerencia: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Para aceptar esta sugerencia tengo que presionar la tecla **flecha derecha** pero me gustaría poder configurar esta tecla a otra de mi preferencia (**tab** me da opciones de lo que puedo escribir pero no acepta la sugerencia) ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Uso Alacritty = 0.11.0 con zsh

Comment: Al presionar `Enter` no la selecciona (acepta)?

Comment: @MauricioContreras  No, al presionar  `Enter` envía hasta donde escribí

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada necesitas acceder al archivo `.zshrc` que es donde configurar tu terminal donde le pones temas y todo, con el siguiente comando:

```
cd .zshrc
```

***Luego se va a abrir lo siguiente:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez ahí te vas al final con la tecla de navegación **(flecha hacia abajo)** y vas a pegar lo siguiente:

```
bindkey '^I' autosuggest-accept
```

Aquí está configurado para la tecla TAB que '^I' viene siendo el TAB eso ya queda a tu criterio.

***Así:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ultimo le das a `ctrl + s` para guarda y ya abres otra pestaña y prueba dándole al tab cuando te sale la predicción.

Comment: No funciona, lo que usted esta intentando hacer es dar un atajo de teclado a un widget que no existe llamada "autosuggest-accept", me parece extraña su respuesta.

Comment: Puede instalar el plugin [Zsh Autosuggestions](https://fig.io/plugins/completion/zsh-autosuggestions) y luego hacer lo de mi respuesta.

Comment: Instala el plugin y luego haces eso, error mío no decir que es un widget del plugin Zsh Autosuggestions.

Comment: !Funciona! Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

para lograr lo que quieres haz lo siguiente:

1. abre una nueva terminal y abre el archivo de configuracion.

   `nano ~/.zshrc`
2. al final de tu archivo agrega esto.

   `bindkey '^Iq' forward-char`

en este ejemplo esta configurado para que acepte con la tecla TAB, en caso quieras cambairlo puedes presonalizar tu combinacion haslo de la siguiente manera `bindkey '^Iq' forward-char` es equivalente a TAB+q.

3.guarda el archivo con `ctrl+O` y cierra con `ctrl+x`.

4. finalmente recarga con `source ~/.zshrc` o abre una nueva terminal para que los cambios se se ejecuten.